# Meaning of 'shoal' and 'darts'

Tags: word-meaning

What 'shoal' and 'darts' mean here?

It's from the book Possession by A.S. Byatt, p70; here is the context>

> “And from all these things the soft light proceeded, like the
>   glimmering of pearls in the depth of water, like the phosphorescent
>   light that moves of itself on the night surface of southern seas, or
>   shines round the heaving **shoals**, milky-white over their silver
>   **darts**, in our own dark Channel.”

Comment: They're shoals of ***fish*** - in context, presumably ***moonlit***, so each individual fish looks like a silver ***dart = projectile***.

Comment: silver darts: actually I think dart is a verb here, sudden rapid movement. Silver because of the apparent colour of the fish.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks.But what does 'their' in 'their silver darts' mean?Is it like 'milky-white over **their** silver **bodies**.'

Comment: @djna Thanks.But if 'darts' here means sudden rapid movement,then what does **'over'** mean?

Comment: the phosphorescent light is milky white on the surface of the ocean above (over) the sudden movements (darts) of the fish

Comment: dubina: What @djna means by *I think dart is a verb here* is he's thinking of it as the "nounified" form of the verb *to dart* (to move rapidly), so it specifically references ***the action of darting*** as done by the fish. Which in principle is a credible deconstruction, but I'm much more comfortable interpreting it as a metaphoric reference to the projectiles people throw at dartboards. It's all *very* "figurative" though, so I wouldn't waste much time trying to figure out exactly what the supposed "literal" interpretation might be.

Comment: My feeling is that in this very poetic context a mundane reference to "One Hundred and Eighty"  is out of place. However that's the beauty of interpretation ... we can cheerfully disagree.

Comment: Why is _moves_ followed by **of**? What does **moves of itself** mean?

Comment: @Deansue: Don't spent too much effort trying to understand either the syntax *or* the meaning of this passage (it's *extremely* flowery / literary / metaphoric, a long way from natural conversational English). The preposition usage in ***moves of itself*** is a rather dated / poetic alternative to ***moves by itself*** (unassisted, under its own steam; it's not being moved by some external force). As to exactly what that *means* in the specific context - it's ***poetry***, and to some extent it "means" whatever it makes you think of.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Crystal clear. Thanks! Makes me never want to read Byatt.

Comment: @Deansue: I don't mean to imply criticism of A.S. Byatt's literary output. But most of it (and certainly the excerpt cited here) isn't really suitable reading material for people who don't already have excellent command of English. Specifically, it's "normal" for ***poetry*** (and "poetic prose") to push the constraints of language to the limit (and sometimes *beyond*). So it should only really be read for the sake of the emotional reactions it invokes, not to learn about syntax, vocabulary, idiomatic usages, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“And from all these things the soft light proceeded, like the glimmering of pearls in the depth of water, like the phosphorescent light that moves of itself on the night surface of southern seas, or shines round the heaving shoals, milky-white over their silver darts, in our own dark Channel.”

shoals means: **all the fish swimming together**

They dart around = move swiftly, darts are like spears.

**So, explained in very simple terms that destroys the poetry of A. S. Byatt:**

the light shines over shoals of fish that move up and down and that look milky-white. The fish are under the water but they are darting around. The fish look like silver spear tips or darts under the surface of the water.

Apologies to the author if she ever sees this. :)